# Url Rewriting - End of url - Removing character after .html

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule products-([0-9]+).html$ products.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule services-([\-]?[0-9]+)-(.+).html$ services.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule objects-([\-]?[0-9]+)-(.+).html$ object.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Wordpress Line

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have an error.

if someone try domain .com/product-6-orange.html/something

he got a the same page as domain .com/product-6-orange.html

I dont want that domain .com/product-6-orange.html/something return a correct answer.

I want that
domain .com/product-6-orange.html/something redirect to domain .com/product-6-orange.html

so anything after .html need to be remove .

but how ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that `domain.com/product-6-orange.html/something` redirect to `domain .com/product-6-orange.html`

Insert this redirect rule just below `RewriteEngine on` line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)/.*$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```